# JavaFX TableView получить данные из ячейки при двойном щелчке мышью по строке

Tags: javafx, tableview

Есть таблица которая содержит несколько колонок с данными абонентов.
Как сделать чтоб после выбора строки с абонентом и нажатия кнопки "просмотр" открывалось окно для редактирования?

Требуется получить объект (абонента) из таблицы, которая содержит базу абонентов. И передать этот объект в новое окно для редактирования полей в базе данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FXML:

```
<TableView fx:id="contractTable" onMouseClicked="#selectContractContractTab" prefHeight="374.0" prefWidth="215.0">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="numberContractColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Номер" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="customerContractColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Заказчик" />
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

На tableView кидаем действие onMouseClicked.

---

Java:

```
public TableView contractTable;

public void selectContractContractTab(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    selectedContract = (Contract) contractTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    //Действие
}
```

В этом методе через `getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` берем выделенный элемент, приводим типы, и дальше делаем уже что хотим (открываем модалку, меняем объект и т.д.).

Если хочешь именно через отдельную кнопку, то присвой этот же метод только кнопке, метод не привязан к action'у, который посылается, так что может использоваться где угодно.

Comment: Спасибо большое